# Push Notification for Ionic Application Using Bluemix

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am building a Hybrid application using Ionic and cordova.
Using PushPlugin i am able to get device token from GCM and APN.
But i am not getting any reference/document/sample project for using bluemix as application server for push notification.
Also some older projects are using applicationId, applicationSecret, routepath but recently bluemix introduced GUID.

How do I use bluemix as application server for Hybrid/Ionic applications?

Comment: you can  also use ngCordova push plugin it is very easy to implement push notification.

Comment: ya...that part i have done...i need details about bluemix push notification for ionic app.